# Links being shifted when clicked (CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 links styled as a list in html, I used this code in CSS to bring them beside each other:

```
li
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

But when I click one of them the other link on the right moves towards the one I clicked.
I don't know the reason why this happening. but how to make them fixed?

The code::
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>
WebMD - Better information. Better Health.
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mainMd.css"/>
<img src="logo_trans.png" class="logo"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<ul class="categories">
<li class="links1" id="symp"><a href="">Symptoms</a></li>
<li class="links1" id="doc"><a href="">Doctors</a></li>
<li class="links1" id="health"><a href="">Health Care Reform</a></li>

</ul>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<aside>
</aside>
<footer>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html
{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to top, white, #F5F9FA);
    height:100%;
}
.logo
{
    padding-left:176px;
    padding-top:4px;
    float:left;
}
 li
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:40px;
    font-family:Candara;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5895D4;
}

#symp
{
    list-style-image:url(walking.png);
    margin-left:55px;
}
#doc
{
    list-style-image:url(doc.png);
}
#health
{
    list-style-image:url(umb.png);
}
li a
{
    color:#5895D4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
li a:active
{
}
li a:visited
{

}
```

Comment: add your HTML and full CSS

Comment: search for `position:relative` on `a:active` selector. this is a part of the `yui-css` reset code.

Comment: *I used this code in CSS to bring them beside each other*. Why not just use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float`?

Comment: I've tried your code and the image bullets beside links disappeared

Comment: we need more code to know what could be causing the behavior

Comment: I've added the full HTML and CSS code.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the CSS selects `li`, not `li a`.

If your HTML structure looks like this:

```
<li><a href=''>Item 1</li>
<li><a href=''>Item 2</li>
```

Try using the following CSS to target the links inside each `li`.

```
li a {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

The reason why your bug might be happening is because `a::visited`is a separate element from `li`. [See MDN's page on :visited.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited)